# Mobile Charging at the Bodie Island Lighthouse

Tags: cellphones, accessibility, remote-locations, north-carolina

The [Bodie Island Lighthouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodie_Island_Lighthouse) is situated on North Carolina's "[Outer Banks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Banks)" within a large system of U. S. national parks known as the [Cape Hatteras National Seashore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Hatteras_National_Seashore).

[image]

Source: [Wiki Creative Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodie_Island_Lighthouse#/media/File:Bodie_Island_Lighthouse,_July_2007.jpg)

On the grounds of the lighthouse, there's a visitor centre, and their [home page](https://www.nps.gov/caha/planyourvisit/visitor-centers.htm) describes it as...

> Approximately six miles south of the seashore's northern entrance is the Bodie Island Visitor Center. This visitor center is located in the historic Bodie Island Lighthouse Double Keepers' Quarters at the end of a short park road off of NC Highway 12 across from Coquina Beach. The visitor center is a great place to get oriented, purchase lighthouse tour tickets, and browse the bookstore.

I went to undergraduate school not far from there and have lots of friends and family in the region and hence contemplate a visit. I'll want to take lots of photos with my mobile but will *not have the stamina to carry additional battery packs*, just a charger cord fitted with a U. S. style mains adapter.

**Question**:  Is there a facility at the lighthouse or visitor centre where I can recharge a mobile? Or more generally, do U. S. national parks provide these facilities? Cape Hatteras is remote and I can imagine lots of visitors having the same question.

Comment: Please see http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/the-great-5-year-anniversary-bounty-bonanza

Comment: Based on your other question, you're traveling here by private car, so why not just get a 12V phone charger and charge in your car?

Comment: I don't think there's going to be a general answer for national parks.  However, most public buildings are equipped with electrical outlets, and staff don't usually object if you plug stuff into them.

Comment: @NateEldredge, didn't think of that 12V thing, that could make a great answer, consider promoting your comment into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier solution is to charge your phone in your car.  You probably have a USB charging cable for your phone.  Some newer cars are equipped with a powered USB port for this purpose; if not, you can get a USB adapter to plug into your car's 12V cigarette adapter.

[image]
(Image credit: Markus Bärlocher via Wikimedia, public domain)

Note that you probably want one with a current rating of at least 2A, or else your phone may charge extremely slowly.  Also, some cars keep the cigarette adapter powered after the key is removed, while others do not.

Comment: +1, Thanks for this alternative, waiting for the bounty cooling off period to elapse.